# Should I (and in what degree) be concerned about EMI/RFI shielding?

Tags: pcb-design, shielding

I am starting on designing a sort of HAT (like used on the RPi) for the [Nvidia Jetson Nano](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-nano-developer-kit).  As I am on my third year of electrical engineering I know little to nothing about EMI and shielding. **Should I (and in what degree) be concerned about EMI/RFI shielding?**

A little info about the project:

- The casing will be containing the Jetson Nano (+HAT), a Raspberry Pi, a HomePlug adapter to interface and power a device outside of the case with a coax cable, and a power converter to power the external device.
- The HAT will provide a connection between the HomePlug device and the Nano, as well as use some AD-converters to read analog input by the user, by means of an analog stick. (0-5V)
- The casing will be about the size of a small office-PC
- The Jetson Nano will drive a monitor attached to the casing

Comment: What kind of motor? Also, you have a Jetson, why add an RPi?

Comment: This depends of what sort of signals you are expecting from the analog input and how accurate you need the output of the ADCs to be. What will the source of the analog input be?

Comment: @MarcusMüller you might have misread, it will drive a monitor. And I’m using a pi for reasons, I believe that there is already software written for it or something like that. It’s out of my control. I’m only concerned about the HAT and the casing.

Comment: @David I have edited my post. It will be an analog stick; no modulated signals, just a potentiometer.

Comment: This isn't a valid question *(any references or places)* for this site. Focus on a specific question you need a solution to.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for your input, I edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Answer: right now!

Comment: @Andyaka What should I ask to get an answer that I actually can use? I've written that I am not experienced at all concerning this subject so this is quite useless.

Comment: A "please teach me all about EMI/EMC" is beyond the scope for this site both as a question and an answer. You may think that this comment is equally useless of course but it's the truth. Study is the keyword here OR ask a specific answerable question.

Comment: I agree. I was aiming for “no you should not be concerned for this type of project” or “yes you should definitely look into it more, you will run into complications if you disregard EMI here” kind of answers. That’s why I asked if I should be concerned, since I have no clue as this is my first “real world” project. I have found some tutorials and videos concerning “how to reduce EMI” but not about “how to find out if it is going to be a problem”. Hence my question.

Comment: If you were building a *product* there would clearly be reasons to be concerned.  Clearly you are not.  Apart from self-interference to any radios (something like an OOK remote control is extremely susceptible, something like WiFi minimally) probably you should just try to follow sound design practices.  Design your board well with proper ground paths minimizing loop area.  Consider putting series ferrites where digital signals approach sensitive circuits or off-board connections, eg, if you have a debug serial connector, you might put ferrites there to prevent the cable from being an antenna.